# proof of $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\sin(x) = \sin(a)$

Tags: limits

Prove with definition that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \sin(x) = \sin(a)$. Is it always true?

Comment: No it's never true.

Comment: Need a specific definition of $\sin x$ to do this.

Comment: @SenZen what does your comment mean? Sine function is continuous.

Comment: Sine is never continuous nowehere

Comment: @SenZen sine is continuous everywhere.

Comment: It is continuous only for negative

Answer (score 0):

Since $\left|\sin x- \sin a\right|=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)\right|\rightarrow 0$ as $\left|x-a\right|\rightarrow 0, $ the desired result follows.

Further, since sine function is continuous, the above limits is always valid.

Comment: Thanks, everyone